# Can I change the value of an attribute passed by constructor of another class?

Tags: java

I want to change a boolean attribute, based in main class, through a constructor.
This is the code:

```
public class NewJDialog{

    public boolean CHECK;
    java.awt.Label label;
.
.
.
    Trasporta valore = new Trasporta(CHECK,label);
.
.
.
}
```

Class2

```
public class Trasporta implementsMouseListener,MouseMotionListener{



public  boolean value;

java.awt.Label label;



public Trasporta(boolean value, java.awt.Label ... pns){

    for ( java.awt.Label genericlabel : pns){
         genericlabel.addMouseListener(this);
         genericlabel.addMouseMotionListener(this);             
    }

   this.value=value;
}




@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {


    this.value = true;
}
```

In this way, CHECK attribute will not become "true".

Can you tell me why?
How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

You declare `CHECK` as primitive type, and not initialize it so it will have default value (primitive boolean are initialized as **false**)

Change your code to

```
Trasporta valore = new Trasporta(true,label);
```

if you want to initialize Transporta class with value = true;

Also, you should read this paper about naming convenction in java
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: that is not answering the question, OP wants to change the value (i`CHECK`) from another later called method (`mousePressed`) - I suppose